# Can't install windows; system doesn't have any boot option

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, windows-installation

Since I cannot successfully boot my computer I decided to do a fresh install of windows 10.

When my pc boots it's actually `preparing for repair` then `diagnosing your pc` then a blue screen telling me my pc didn't start correctly.

When I go in advanced options I can click on use a device then `EFI USB DEVICE`. My computer then restart and a message appears on screen:

> System doesn't have any USB boot option. Please select other boot
>   option in Boot Manager Menu..

I click ok then the Boot Option menu appears and I can pick between:

- Window Boot Manager (samsung MZVLW128HEGR)  // I believe this is my SSD
- EPI PXE Network

None of those 2 work.

---

In my Bios Boot panel I have

```
Boot Mode: UEF1
FAST BOOT: Enabled
USB Boot: Enabled
PXE Boot to LAN: enabled
IPV4 PXE: first Enabled

-- EFI --
Window Boot Manager (samsung MZVLW128HEGR)
EPI PXE Network
```

I'm unsure what I need to do, I can access the command prompt still, so maybe there is something I could try from there ?

Comment: You need to boot into your BIOS and enable EFI USB boot.

Comment: @AFH isn't that what's already enabled in the settings I pasted in the question above ? It's the content of the whole boot panel.

Comment: I have a different BIOS on each motherboard, but the bootable devices are configured outside the boot menu itself. Sometimes a boot device does not appear in the boot menu unless it holds a valid, bootable OS.

Comment: Like @afh suggested, the boot devices won’t show up unless the USB drive has a valid UEFI bootable partition. How did you make the Windows 10 installation USB? It should’ve been done with this [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)

Comment: Please add your exact computer model or motherboard model for custom built PCs.

Comment: @tool it was made with that tool

Comment: @jdwolf it's a lenovo y520

Comment: Buggy UEFI is always fun.

Comment: @Ced Add your model to the question especially considering this problem is specific to Lenovo.

Comment: Try disabling Fast boot and setting boot priory to USB HDD and cold boot.